# How to take n elements from numpy array and add them to separate list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

If I have an numpy array that contain n elements. How can I create a list choosing specific ranges from that array?

```
array_input = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
A = array_input[]
B = array_input[]
C = array_input[]
```

I want to know what I have to type in the brackets so that output is:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]

B = [4, 5, 6]

C = [7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: What exactly is your end goal? Why do you need three separate lists? Why not just use the array?

Comment: i just want to know how to extract elements of from array within specific range and add them to another list...

Comment: *But why*? What is your ultimate goal? If you have a numpy array, why do you want a list instead? For example you could just do `array_input.reshape(-1,3)` and now you have an array with 2 dimensions, shape (3,3)... in which case, you can just access each row using regular indexing.

Comment: I think you're looking for `A = array_input[0:3]`, `B = array_input[3:6]` and `C = array_input[6:9]`. But as others have commented, if A, B and C are going to get some kind of similar treatment, you're probably better off converting to a 2D array and processing that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a numpy.ndarray object to begin with, why not just work with that? Reshape it:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> arr = arr.reshape(3,-1)
>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> arr[0]
array([1, 2, 3])
```

And this would probably suit your needs. If you *insist* on creating three separate lists, you can just do something like:

```
>>> A, B, C = arr.reshape(3, -1).tolist()
>>> A
[1, 2, 3]
>>> B
[4, 5, 6]
>>> C
[7, 8, 9]
```